# Interpolation of differentials

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $x_1,..x_n$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Let $A_1,..,A_n$ be $p\times p$ symmetric positive definite matrices. I would like to prove this: there exists a diffeo $f$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$ such that $df_{x_i}=A_i$.

Can somebody tell me if it is possible (and how) to prove it without giving a construction of $f$, or if this is a consequence of a known theorem?

Comment: Note that this is not possible if $E = \Bbb R$.  For instance, there is no diffeomorphism $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f'(1) = 1$ and $f'(2) = -1$, since any map satisfying these conditions fails to be injective.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified my question, I think it is correct now.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not interested in an explicit construction? That would be the usual way I would attempt such a thing.

Comment: Giving a construction seems quite fastidious... Unless I just miss how to properly address it.

Comment: Not sure why you want to evade its use, but that "fastidious" thing is called "partition of unity", which is a powerful conceptual device to extend a local construction to a global construction.

Comment: I'm not sure how a partition of unity would work here. Note that invertability or positive definiteness of the differential is not preserved under a partition of unity, nor is injectivity, nor is surjectivity. This question seems hard to me.